# inserting serialized array in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization

I am trying to insert a serialized array into mysql without column names, is it possible?

I plan to use this in a function with a dynamic number of textboxes so I will just call the function and pass the tablename and insert into the database in order.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
<form action = "" method = "POST">

    Username: <input required type = "text" name = "register[]" / ><br />
    Password: <input required type = "text" name = "register[]" / ><br />
    Usertype: <input required type = "text" name = "register[]"  / ><br />
    Status:   <input required type = "text" name = "register[]" / ><br />
    <input  type = "submit" name = "add" value = "add" / >

</form>

if(isset($_POST['add']))
{

    $reg = serialize($_POST['register']); //takes the data from a post operation...
    $register = mysql_real_escape_string($reg);
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES('$register')");    
}
```

working queries:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,usertype,status) VALUES('$register','2','3','4')");
```

output:

a:4:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"1";i:2;s:1:"1";i:3;s:1:"1";}
2
3
4

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You can do it.

Comment: So what is the problem??

Comment: You forgot to include the column name in your insert query.

Comment: it is not inserting to my database ive checked the database connection and tried to insert values manually and it works fine.but when i use serialize it just doesnt work

Comment: @LoganWayne im trying to insert it without column name because im going to use this as a function and dynamic numbers of input so i will just call the function and pass the tablename

Comment: Joe. Welcome to Stackoverflow. I see you've provided extra details in the comments. Please update your question with the additional details you've provided in the comments section. This should help people help you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use PHP `serialize()` to conveniently insert multiple data into multiple MySQL fields. `serialze()` transforms complex php's type into single string. One single string. You may use it to store an array with all these values into one text field, but that is not what you wanted.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (username,password,usertype,status)
 VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_query($_POST['register'][0])."',
 '".mysql_real_escape_query($_POST['register'][1])."',
 '".mysql_real_escape_query($_POST['register'][2])."',
 '".mysql_real_escape_query($_POST['register'][3])."' )");
```

---

Alternatively using PDO:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost','root','pass');
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO users (username,password,usertype,status)
  VALUES(?,?,?,?)');
$sth->execute($_POST['register']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the fieldnames of table

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user(username,password,usertype,status) VALUES('$register')");
```

Comment: is it possible to not have fieldnames? because im going to use this as a function and dynamic number of input so i will just call the function and pass the tablename and insert it to database in order

Comment: you mean, you will include the fieldnames in the function as parameter?

Comment: no just insert it without fieldnames just in order of the array/serial is it possible?

Comment: I think it is possible but it cannot be random and make sure the array count is the same as total count of fieldnames in your table

Comment: i tried to echo the array using for each and its 4 the same as my fieldname (not including the id/primary key) what do you mean random? randomly arrange in array?

Comment: "INSERT INTO user" is different from "INSERT INTO uesr(username,password,type,status)" if you have id/primary key

Comment: I mean not random. (username,pass,type,status) in order

Comment: yes i do have a primary key so can it still be inserted without column name? should it be like this?
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user VALUES(null,'$register')");

Comment: Nope, not null because it is integer, get the last id then increment, then get the value.

Comment: but my primary is set for auto incriment should it not be just increment automatically?

Comment: i tried null like (null,'1','2','3','4') and it works but
(null,'$register') its not working

Comment: thanks for answering i already solved it but using a different method i use implode

Answer (score 0):

i madeit work but using a different method i used implode but its the same

```
$register = "'" . implode("','", $_POST['register']) . "'";
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES(null,$register)");
```

Comment: Please, not like this, very vulnerable to mysql injection attack.

Comment: im going to change it to mysqli and myrealescape